# load Data before go to a View

Tags: angularjs, angular, router

I have an app with different roles like : admin, user.
So now I want to fetch all the data before going to a specific view

```
    this.rollesService.getRollesByID(this.jwt.Id).subscribe(
  data => this.Rolles= data,
  err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)),
  () => //go to Path;
```

if the a user put in a URL like

questions/ask

the app firstly should load the Data before going to this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the view in `ngIf` where the condition becomes `true` when the data is available.